# Microsoft Account OpenID authentication token request returns id_token but not access_token

Tags: oauth, openid, microsoft-graph-api

In the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code

... it states that a successful response to a token request looks like:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1Q...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read",
    "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4...",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyZDRkMTFhMi1mODE0LTQ2YTctOD...",
}
```

After the first step of authentication completes, I receive a code on the redirect and use it to request a token.

However, I only receive this:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyZDRkMTFhMi1mODE0LTQ2YTctOD...",
}
```

My scope is set to `openid email profile`.

Why do I not receive the `access_token`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access token will be returned only when resource specific scopes are requested, so that it can used to access the protected resource. Try including a scope like "https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read" as indicated in sample present in the documentation link posted with the question.